# Amazon Web Services Missing Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

Sorry, I am really new to this AWS. I am stuck since yesterday.

Our former developer creates an app and it is on AWS, unfortunately, we can't find the Instances on the account he created. But we can still access the IP, and also, there's nothing on the account Elastic IP.

It is either, there's a different account, or i am missing something.

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons for this could be that you are looking in the wrong region. In your AWS console, try to switch to the relevant region(s) to find the instance.

Another way is, if you have access to the Cost Explorer, then you may be able to see your all billed resources and that can help you find the instance too.

EDIT: To see the details of EC2 instances in cost explore, go to the Bills from the left menu and check "Bill details by service" (default tab). You will be able to drill into instances level. Here is a snapshot

[image]

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your reply, as far as I know, we are only using FREE Tier.

Regarding the "Relevant Regions", what do you mean exactly? Sorry, noob question

Comment: I found this on Cost Explorer:

Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud running Linux/UNIX$0.00

per Linux t2.micro instance-hour (or partial hour) under monthly free tier

Comment: @NoobDev Check my edit to the answer for additional info.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you, and that's where i found this.

https://ibb.co/TYP705t